# Creating table using for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table

I am trying to create a simple times table in a html document using Javascript. This is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Table</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        for (var a=0; a < 10; a++) {
            document.write("<tr>");
            for(var b=0; b<10; b++) {
                document.write("<td>"a*b"</td>");
        }
        document.write("</tr>");
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I looked through the posted questions, but could not find an answer, possibly because I am a beginner programmer and did not understand most of it.

Comment: `document.write("<td>" + (a*b) + "</td>");`?

Comment: Indeed, you have to concatenate your strings properly using the `+` sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all you should insert the tr (rows) and td (cells) into a table element... Something like

```
document.write("<table>");
// your loop here
document.write("</table>");
```

There are better ways to do this, though!

Comment: Glad it worked! :) would you mind flagging the answer as the correct one please? It means a lot to me, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function table()
{
 this.calcmul = calc;
}
 function calc(arg1,arg2)
 {
  var multi = (arg1 * arg2);
  return multi; 
 }
 var table2 = new table();  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="solid 2px;" style="font-size:50px;">
 <thead><tr>
   <script>
   for(var j=1; j<=10; j++)
   {
    document.write("<th><label style='color:red;'>"+i+"</label></th>");
   }
   </script>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
for(var i =1; i<=10; i++)
{
 document.write("<tr>");
 for(var k=1; k<=10; k++)
  {
   var arg1 = i;
   var arg2 = k; 
   document.write("<td>"+table2.calcmul(arg1,arg2)+"</td>"); 
  }
 document.write("</tr>"); 
} 
</script>
 </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `'+'` to concate.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Table</title>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
for (var a=0; a < 10; a++) {
document.write("<tr>");
for(var b=0; b<10; b++) {
document.write("<td>"+(a*b)+"</td>");
}
document.write("</tr>");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var students = [`Ahsan`,`Ali`,`Moiz`,`Raza`,`Zia`];
var rollNums = [10,20,30,40,50];
document.write(`<table>
<th>Student Name</th>
<th>Roll Num</th>`)
for (var i = 0 ; i < students.length ; i++){
    document.write(`
    <tr>
        <td>${students[i]}</td>
        <td>${rollNums[i]}</td>
    </tr> <br />`)
};
document.write(`</table>`)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This might be another way of creating table using Vanilla Javascript without any tag

```js
var table = document.createElement('table')
table.setAttribute('border', 1) // optional styling
var body = table.createTBody()

for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
  var row = body.insertRow(a)
  for (var b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
    row.insertCell(b).innerText = (a + 1) * (b + 1)
  }
}

document.body.appendChild(table)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Table</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function calc(arg1,arg2)
 {
  var multi = (arg1 * arg2);
  return multi; 
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="solid 2px;" style="color:black;font-size:50px;">
 <thead><tr>
   <script>
   for(var j=1; j<=10; j++)
   {
    document.write("<th>"+i+"</th>");
   }
   </script>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
<script>
for(var i =1; i<=10; i++)
{
 document.write("<tr>");
 for(var k=1; k<=10; k++)
  {
   var arg1 = i;
   var arg2 = k; 
   document.write("<td>"+calc(arg1,arg2)+"</td>"); 
  }
 document.write("</tr>"); 
} 
</script>
 </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<div id="yr" class="year"></div>
function year(){
    var test = '<table border="1px"><thead><tr><th><</th><th colspan="2">2015-2016</th><th>></th><tr></thead><tbody>';
    var tr='';
    for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
        tr += '<tr>';
        for(var j=0;j<4;j++){
            tr += '<td>'+2015+'</td>';
            }
        }
        tr +='</tr>';
    test += tr;
    return document.getElementById('yr').innerHTML = test;
}
year();
```

Comment: Fixed rows and columns

Answer (score -3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function calc(arg1,arg2)
 {
  var multi = (arg1 * arg2);
  return multi; 
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="solid 2px;" style="color:black;font-size:50px;">
 <thead><tr>
   <script>
   for(var j=1; j<=10; j++)
   {
    document.write("<th>"+i+"</th>");
   }
   </script>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
<script>
for(var i =1; i<=10; i++)
{
 document.write("<tr>");
 for(var k=1; k<=10; k++)
  {
   var arg1 = i;
   var arg2 = k; 
   document.write("<td>"+calc(arg1,arg2)+"</td>"); 
  }
 document.write("</tr>"); 
} 
</script>
 </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```